# vb6 Retrieve IPV6 from local host or remote ip address

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb6, asp-classic

I'm trying to find a resource to get a few things about the user identity for security purposes.  I'm trying to get ipv6 ipaddress, and the computer name or host name using classic asp and vb6.  If I can't use vb6 I would like to use jQuery or javascript if possible.

In asp, I can get the ipv4 using request.ServerObject("REMOTE_ADDR") I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this in ASP I'm unaware of anything you can use to get this directly.

It is possible to write a Class in VB6 that calls DnsQuery in Dnsapi.dll to do first a DNS_TYPE_PTR query to reverse-lookup the IPv4 address to get the DNS name and then a DNS_TYPE_AAAA query to retrieve the corresponding IPv6 address (if any).

...

Hmm, no code handout no rep eh?  (insert smiley here)

Well this is a bit of code to post here inline... maybe look at [{VB6} DNS Lookup Class](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=644195) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but there is some information here about building a GUI in VB to track an IP address:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkDD03yeLnU

Comment: Maybe I should switch this as the answer?